# Batch script for checking if a server is online

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, network-programming, ping

I basically want to have a windows batch script which goes through a list of servers and checks every server with a ping if it is online.
The list of servers should be a simple plain text file and should look something like this:

```
...
"Google" www.google.com
"Node1" 221.12.123.1
"Download Server" dl.myserver.com
"Login Server" login.myserver.com
...
```

Here is a simple rundown what the program should do:

1. print a list of the descriptions of all the servers in the list to the screen.
2. ping the first server server 4 times if one ping succeeds it should return online if all 4 pings fail it should return offline.
3. print online or offline next to the first server in the printed list
4. run step 2 and 3 for all other servers in the list.

The output should look like the following:

```
...
Google: online
Stackoverflow: online
Node1: online
Download Server: offline
Login server: offline
...
```

I just want to know if this is even possible in (windows) batch and how to do it. If it isn't possible in batch, what programming language should I use? Would it be possible to program this in Python?

I would also be really thankful if anybody could post the code how to do this, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f usebackq^ tokens^=1^,2^ delims^=^" %%a in ("servers.txt") do (
        call :isOnline %%b && set "status=online" || set "status=offline"
        echo %%a : !status!
    )

    endlocal

    exit /b

:isOnline address
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: a temporary file is needed to capture ping output for later processing
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    :: ping the indicated address and get errorlevel
    ping -w 1000 -n 4 %~1 > "%tempFile%"  && set "pingError=" || set "pingError=1"

    :: When pinging, 
    ::
    :: we get errorlevel = 1 when
    ::    ipv4 - when any packet is lost. It is necessary to check for "TTL="
    ::           string in the output of the ping command.
    ::    ipv6 - when all packet are lost.
    :: we get errorlevel = 0 when
    ::    ipv4 - all packets received. But pinging a inactive host on the  
    ::           same subnet result in no packet lost. It is necessary to 
    ::           check for "TTL=" string in the output of the ping command.
    ::    ipv6 - at least one packet reaches the host.
    ::
    ::                          +--------------+-------------+
    ::                          | TTL= present |    No TTL   | 
    ::  +-----------------------+--------------+-------------+
    ::  | ipv4    errorlevel 0  |      OK      |    ERROR    |
    ::  |         errorlevel 1  |      OK      |    ERROR    | 
    ::  +-----------------------+--------------+-------------+ 
    ::  | ipv6    errorlevel 0  |              |      OK     |
    ::  |         errorlevel 1  |              |    ERROR    |
    ::  +-----------------------+----------------------------+
    ::
    :: So, if TTL= is present in output, host is online. If errorlevel is 0 
    :: and the address is ipv6 then host is online. In the rest of the cases
    :: the host is offline.    
    ::
    :: To determine the ip version, a regular expresion to match a ipv6 
    :: address is used with findstr. As it will be only tested in the case 
    :: of no errorlevel, the ip address should be present in the output of
    :: ping command.

    set "exitCode=1"
    find "TTL=" "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul && set "exitCode=0" || (
        if not defined pingError (
            findstr /r /c:" [a-f0-9:][a-f0-9]*:[a-f0-9:%%]*[a-f0-9]: " "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul  && set "exitCode=0"
        )
    )

    :: cleanup and return errorlevel
    if exist "%tempFile%" del /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul 
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Comment: With Windows 10 1803 you could use CURL instead of ping. The Success and Failure detection is easier: 
`curl -s -m 2 servername > nul && echo offline || echo online`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily in batch, you just need some `for /f` loops, `echo` statements, `if` statements, `goto`/`call` statements and use the `ping` command.

> 1.print a list of the descriptions of all the servers in the list to the
>   screen.

You can use `echo` statement for this, like `echo "Google" www.google.com`

> 2.ping the first server server 4 times if one ping succeeds it should
>   return online if all 4  pings fail it should return offline.

inside a `for /f` loop [like `for /f "tokens=5 delims==, " %%p in (`], you can use the `ping` command with 4 trys like so `ping -n 4 www.google.com`

> 3.print online or offline next to the first server in the printed list

you can use and `if` statemenet here, like so: `if "%status%"=="online" echo Google: online` or just `echo Google: %status%`

> 4.run step 2 and 3 for all other servers in the list.

You can use a `goto` or a `call` statement here (use it like a function), for example: `call :server_status_function www.google.com`

Comment: could you please post the whole code for the script here? because I don't understand how to get the descriptions and ip-adresses from the file.