# How to set variable in dos batch file that show only result

Tags: batch-file

how to display only status of ping result like this- here is "My serverx is...fixed only change the online / offline status.

** My server1 is .... online

** My server2 is .... online

** My server3 is .... offline

i was try to this..but fail

```
@echo off
ping My server1|find "Reply from " >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Success
IF     ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Fail

ping My server2|find "Reply from " >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Success
IF     ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Fail

ping My server3|find "Reply from " >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Success
IF     ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Fail

echo My server1 is ....%ver%
echo My server2 is ....%ver%
echo My server3 is ....%ver%
```

how to set variable here to do like this.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23720500/2861476) could help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one line per server this way:

```
ping -n 1 server1 | find "TTL=" >NUL && echo server1 is online. || echo server1 is offline.
ping -n 1 server2 | find "TTL=" >NUL && echo server2 is online. || echo server2 is offline.
ping -n 1 server3 | find "TTL=" >NUL && echo server3 is online. || echo server3 is offline.
```

It's basically shorthand for

```
ping -n 1 server1 | find "TTL=" >NUL
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo server1 is online.
) else (
    echo server1 is offline.
)
```

... etc.  If your hosts you're pinging are sequential, you could use perhaps even less code by employing a `for /L` loop or similar, something like this:

```
for /L %%I in (1,1,254) do (
    ping -n 1 192.168.0.%%I | find "TTL=" >NUL && echo 192.168.0.%%I is online. || echo 192.168.0.%%I is offline.
)
```

Type `help for` in a cmd console for more information about `for /L`.

**Edit:** See MC ND's comment immediately below regarding trusting `ping` to set the errorlevel.  Even the example in the question above looking for `Reply from` can result in a false success.  Using `find "TTL="` to set errorlevel is more reliable.

For more info on conditional execution, [read this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php).

Comment: errorlevel is not a reliable way to check for ping sucess. In ipv4, errorlevel is set if any packet is lost, and pinging an inactive machine on the same vlan will result in a non reachable machine with no packet lost and no errorlevel. And the behaviour is different for ipv6 (more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23720500/2861476))

Comment: I see.  I just pinged a non-existent host within my subnet and got "Reply from (my local machine): Destination host unreachable", but `%ERRORLEVEL%` was 0. I like your idea of watching for `TTL=`.

Comment: @MCND as a matter of interest, if what you're checking is a group of web servers and you'd like a script to check whether the HTTP service on each returns a status of "200 OK", [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15395490/1683264) has a script that does that.  Pretty clever!

Comment: Hi rojo, i appreciate your answer and try to make it.